# generating test flight failed with me

Tags: xcode, testflight

generating test flight for the first time

Hello everyone, I have been granted access to the App Store Connect as an admin by my friend who is the owner of an individual Apple developer account. I am using my own Apple ID for this access.

However, when attempting to generate a TestFlight build in Xcode, I encounter two errors:

> "Failed to register bundle identifier"

and

> "No profiles for '...' were found." These errors occur when I try to add my Apple ID and enable the "Automatically manage signing" option.

I would like to know what steps I should take to generate a TestFlight build using my own Apple ID instead of my friend's.

Are there any additional actions, such as adding specific certificates, identifiers, or profiles, that my friend needs to configure for me, beyond granting me access to App Store Connect?